# ant command from powershell - dot used as delimiter for parameter?

Tags: powershell, ant

I'm trying to run an ant task which I'm invoking from a powershell script:

```
Invoke-Expression "ant -f $antFilePath -Dtestsuite=$testsuite clean compile run"
```

The $testsuite variable is a string which includes a dot character, e.g. "systemTest.All", so:

```
Invoke-Expression "ant -f $antFilePath -Dtestsuite=systemTest.All clean compile run"
```

My problem is that the dot seems to be interpreted as a delimiter (by powershell? Invoking from cmd works just fine), hence the "All" part gets treated as a ant target (among with clean compile run).

(The use of a dot in the testsuite name is not one of mine doings so that part I can not affect)

Do I need to qoute the ant argument, escape the dot in some way?

Br,
Pete

Comment: I don't have `ant` at hand here, but I'd try quoting the argument first: ``"ant -f ... -Dtestsuite=`"$testsuite`" ..."``

Comment: Then I get the error: -Dtestsuite="systemWarmup.RunAll <<<<
 " compile run
is missing the terminator: ".      ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this (but I can't test it), run this directly w/o invoke-Expression:

```
ant -f $antFilePath "-Dtestsuite=$testsuite" clean compile run
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Too bad I found this after I had figured it out already.